# How should I format this for a Jade Layout?

Tags: html, node.js, pug

I am trying to format this HTML into Jade:

```
<div class="textItem">
    <div class="avatar">
        <img src="http://wowthemes.net/demo/biscaya/img/demo/avatar.jpg" alt="avatar">
    </div>
    "How often have I said to you that when you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth?<span style="font-family:arial;">"</span><br/><b>Ralph G. Flowers </b>
</div>
```

I have tried this approach, but it tries to turn the text into another tag:

```
.textItem
    .avatar
        img(src="http://wowthemes.net/demo/biscaya/img/demo/avatar.jpg" alt="avatar")
    "How often have I said to you that when you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth?<span style="font-family:arial;">"</span><br/><b>Ralph G. Flowers </b>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
doctype html
html(lang="en")
  head
  body
    .textItem
    .avatar
        img(src="http://wowthemes.net/demo/biscaya/img/demo/avatar.jpg" alt="avatar")
        | How often have I said to you that when you have eliminated the impossible, whatever remains, however improbable, must be the truth?
        span(style="font-family:arial")
        br
        | Ralph G. Flowers
        br
```

That should give you what I think you are trying for.